# How to convert Decimal128 to decimal in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with many (But not all) Decimal128 columns (taken from a mongodb collection).  I can't perform any math or comparisons on them (e.g. '<' not supported between instances of 'Decimal128' and 'float').

What is the quickest/easiest way to convert all these to float or some simpler built-in type that i can work with?

There is the Decimal128 to_decimal() method, and pandas astype(), but how can I do it for all (the decimal128) columns in one step/helper method?

Edit, I've tried:

```
testdf =  my_df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).astype(float) if isinstance(x, Decimal128) else x)

testdf[testdf["MyCol"] > 80].head()
```

but I get:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Decimal128' and 'int'
```

Converting a single column using .astype(str).astype(float) works.

Comment: I think the isinstance method is returning false and hence the columns are not being converted to float. I think if you use the the exact class of Decimal128, this method will work.

Comment: they're all instances of 'object', rather than str or Decimal128.

Comment: Can you show how your dataframe looks?

Comment: looks like most are correct, apart from strings are coming in as dtype object

Comment: Think i'll have to do it column by column rather than automating it. thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Casting full DataFrame.

```
df = df.astype(str).astype(float)
```

For single column. **IDs** is the name of the column.

```
df["IDs"] = df.IDs.astype(str).astype(float)
```

Test implementation

```
from pprint import pprint
import bson
df = pd.DataFrame()
y = []
for i in range(1,6):
    i = i *2/3.5
    y.append(bson.decimal128.Decimal128(str(i)))
pprint(y)
df["D128"] = y
df["D128"] = df.D128.astype(str).astype(float)
print("\n", df)
```

Output:

```
[Decimal128('0.5714285714285714'),
 Decimal128('1.1428571428571428'),
 Decimal128('1.7142857142857142'),
 Decimal128('2.2857142857142856'),
 Decimal128('2.857142857142857')]

        D128
0  0.571429
1  1.142857
2  1.714286
3  2.285714
4  2.857143
```

Comment: Gives "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Decimal128'"

Comment: @Rich Updated the answer. Can you please check now and let me know if that works. :)

Comment: casting through string seems to work. Doesn't look very efficient but hey-ho

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
df = df.astype(float)
```

You can also use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) or [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)(applying element wise operations), although these are inefficient compared to previous method.

```
df = df.applymap(float)
```

I can't reproduce a Decimal128 number in my system. Can you please check if the next line works for you?

```
df =  df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(float) if isinstance(x, bson.decimal.Decimal128) else x)
```

It will check if a column is of type Decimal128 and then convert it to float.

Comment: Can you do this solely for the decimal128 columns?  e.g. foreach column if decimal128 then convert, else leave it alone?

Comment: Hi @Rich I've edited my answer. Can you please have a look and tell me if it works for you?