# How to get full decimal values from the column in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dictionary with columns as shown below

[image]

The values if i copy from variable explorer and paste in my script, i get more decimals values, as shown below

[image]

I create a subset dataframe with 'good' and 'values' columns in dict as follows,
I convert the column values as array

```
subset_df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['good','values'])
subset_df = subset_df.astype(dtype={'good': float, 'values': float})

for c1 in data.keys():
    subset_df = subset_df.append({'good': data[c1].good.values, 'values': data[c1].value.values},ignore_index = True)

subset_df.to_csv("subset_data.csv", sep=',', index=False)
```

The values of value column as array is not stored with full decimals, in my csv i get

```
[ 0.00514096 -4.47819049 -2.92872443 -1.96271026 -0.97532361 -2.26499113]
```

How to get the full decimal values shown in 2nd picture into my csv?

Comment: Use `decimal` instead of `float`. Take a look at this [How to convert Decimal128 to decimal in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53351707/3091398)

Comment: I did 'import decimal' and assigned dtype as decimal.Decimal, getting TypeError: dtype '<class 'decimal.Decimal'>' not understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @CodeIt comments, I tried as follows and worked

```
import decimal

for c1 in data.keys():
    subset_df = subset_df.append({'good': data[c1].good.values.astype(decimal.Decimal), 'values': data[c1].value.values.astype(decimal.Decimal)},ignore_index = True)
```

In my csv I got

```
[0.0051409609131047584 -4.478190490710133 -2.9287244281198306
 -1.962710260893245 -0.9753236073353595 -2.2649911327661783]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is inbuilt in `to_csv` function.

`df.to_csv('subset_data.csv', float_format='%10.50f')`

Here`10` refers to 10 places from the start till end.
Lets say you have more decimal places you can increase to `100.100f`.
The only problem with this is if you have less than 50 decimals with in the values if would assign 0s at the end.

Try the below example you can see:

```
import pandas as pd

a = [1.2323465373673547547,
    3.357436538737863876387,
    -3.8457458725625825,
    -0.2685673458375796973,
    4273.486487358632297629879,
    89.86775437653783387287,
    90948647.63488738769386083]

df = pd.DataFrame(a)

df.to_csv('del.csv', float_format='%100.50f')
```

If you want to get the number of decimal places and use it as input,
Then:

```
d = decimal.Decimal('56.43256436')
d.as_tuple().exponent
```

And use this value for `float_format`.

[image: Output]

Comment: This solution works for values specified, Here getting the array as data[c1].value.values doesn't give me the full decimals

Comment: you probably have to tweak the float_format...read the docs about it there are a few examples but mostly you have to tune manually.